# Which selector shall I use to go to a specific location with scroll in a <ul>

Tags: javascript, jquery

The title is not really clear since I don't really know how to express that neither I know exactly where does the problem come from. I'm still new, and have spent a lot of hour on this without any result and I'm a bit getting desperate.

The idea is to render as does a select when you type a letter and heading to it into your select.

However for style purpose I do not use a select but a `<ul>` which has been stylised with `overflow:scroll` and a maximum height.

Have a look at **[this JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Baldrani/xu83c23f/)**

I'm having a lot of trouble especially when I try to find good test to use.

This is what I have done so far : The code is comment so you can see the part working or not and what I thought of it.

Actually I'm not really sure of what is not working or what is especially blocking.

If you guys can give me a hint I would so appreciate !

```
$('.custom-select').click(function() {
    var res = "";
    document.onkeydown = f;
    /* Create a String of what we are looking for;
       works but not that beautiful (especially the part of e.preventDefault) */
    function f(e) {
        clearTimeout(f);

        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        if (e.keyCode == 8) {
            res = res.slice(0, -1);
        } else {
            res += String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
            if (res.length > 5) {
                res = "";
            }
        }
        console.log(res);
        setTimeout(f, 3000);
    }
    /* Half working ? Not sure I'm using the right selector */
    $(this).next($('.customSelect').find('li').each(function() {
        if ($(this).innerText == res) {
            /* Works (Just for scrool) */
            $('.customSelect').animate({
                scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
            }, 500)
        }
    }))
})
```

### Here is the HTML for understanding purpose

```
<div class="search-content">
    <div class="relative">
        <div class="custom-select">Sélectionnez un pays</div>
        <ul class="customSelect" id="countries" name="countries">
            <li class="title not" data-value="0">Top destinations</li>
            <li data-value="1" onclick="setinfos('country',1);"> Andorre</li>
            <li data-value="2" onclick="setinfos('country',2);"> Émirats Arabes Unis</li>
            <li data-value="3" onclick="setinfos('country',3);"> Afghanistan</li>
            <li data-value="4" onclick="setinfos('country',4);"> Antigua-et-Barbuda</li>
            <li data-value="5" onclick="setinfos('country',5);"> Anguilla</li>
            <li data-value="6" onclick="setinfos('country',6);"> Albanie</li>
            <li data-value="7" onclick="setinfos('country',7);"> Arménie</li>
            <li data-value="8" onclick="setinfos('country',8);"> Angola</li>
            <li data-value="9" onclick="setinfos('country',9);"> Antarctique</li>
            <li data-value="10" onclick="setinfos('country',10);"> Argentine</li>
            <li data-value="11" onclick="setinfos('country',11);"> Samoa Américaines</li>
            <li data-value="12" onclick="setinfos('country',12);"> Autriche</li>
            <li data-value="13" onclick="setinfos('country',13);"> Australie</li>
            <li data-value="14" onclick="setinfos('country',14);"> Aruba</li>
            <li data-value="15" onclick="setinfos('country',15);"> Îles Åland</li>
            <li data-value="16" onclick="setinfos('country',16);"> Azerbaïdjan</li>
            <li data-value="17" onclick="setinfos('country',17);"> Bosnie-Herzégovine</li>
            <li data-value="18" onclick="setinfos('country',18);"> Barbade</li>
            <li data-value="19" onclick="setinfos('country',19);"> Bangladesh</li>
            <li data-value="20" onclick="setinfos('country',20);"> Belgique</li>
            <li data-value="21" onclick="setinfos('country',21);"> Burkina Faso</li>
            <li data-value="22" onclick="setinfos('country',22);"> Bulgarie</li>
            <li data-value="23" onclick="setinfos('country',23);"> Bahreïn</li>
            <li data-value="24" onclick="setinfos('country',24);"> Burundi</li>
            <li data-value="25" onclick="setinfos('country',25);"> Bénin</li>
            <li data-value="26" onclick="setinfos('country',26);"> Saint-Barthélemy</li>
            <li data-value="27" onclick="setinfos('country',27);"> Bermudes</li>
            <li data-value="28" onclick="setinfos('country',28);"> Brunei</li>
            <li data-value="29" onclick="setinfos('country',29);"> Bolivie</li>
            <li data-value="30" onclick="setinfos('country',30);"> Bonaire</li>
            <li data-value="31" onclick="setinfos('country',31);"> Brésil</li>
            <li data-value="32" onclick="setinfos('country',32);"> Bahamas</li>
            <li data-value="33" onclick="setinfos('country',33);"> Bhoutan</li>
            <li data-value="34" onclick="setinfos('country',34);"> Île Bouvet</li>
            <li data-value="35" onclick="setinfos('country',35);"> Botswana</li>
            <li data-value="36" onclick="setinfos('country',36);"> Bélarus</li>
            <li data-value="37" onclick="setinfos('country',37);"> Belize</li>
            <li data-value="38" onclick="setinfos('country',38);"> Canada</li>
            <li data-value="39" onclick="setinfos('country',39);"> Îles Cocos</li>
            <li data-value="40" onclick="setinfos('country',40);"> République démocratique du Congo</li>
            <li data-value="41" onclick="setinfos('country',41);"> Centrafrique</li>
            <li data-value="42" onclick="setinfos('country',42);"> République du Congo</li>
            <li data-value="43" onclick="setinfos('country',43);"> Suisse</li>
            <li data-value="44" onclick="setinfos('country',44);"> Côte d'Ivoire</li>
            <li data-value="45" onclick="setinfos('country',45);"> Îles Cook</li>
            <li data-value="46" onclick="setinfos('country',46);"> Chili</li>
            <li data-value="47" onclick="setinfos('country',47);"> Cameroun</li>
            <li data-value="48" onclick="setinfos('country',48);"> Chine</li>
            <li data-value="49" onclick="setinfos('country',49);"> Colombie</li>
            <li data-value="50" onclick="setinfos('country',50);"> Costa Rica</li>
            <li data-value="51" onclick="setinfos('country',51);"> Cuba</li>
            <li data-value="52" onclick="setinfos('country',52);"> Cap-vert</li>
            <li data-value="53" onclick="setinfos('country',53);"> Curaçao</li>
            <li data-value="54" onclick="setinfos('country',54);"> Île Christmas</li>
            <li data-value="55" onclick="setinfos('country',55);"> Chypre</li>
            <li data-value="56" onclick="setinfos('country',56);"> République Tchèque</li>
            <li data-value="57" onclick="setinfos('country',57);"> Allemagne</li>
            <li data-value="58" onclick="setinfos('country',58);"> Djibouti</li>
            <li data-value="59" onclick="setinfos('country',59);"> Danemark</li>
            <li data-value="60" onclick="setinfos('country',60);"> Dominique</li>
            <li data-value="61" onclick="setinfos('country',61);"> République Dominicaine</li>
            <li data-value="62" onclick="setinfos('country',62);"> Algérie</li>
            <li data-value="63" onclick="setinfos('country',63);"> Équateur</li>
            <li data-value="64" onclick="setinfos('country',64);"> Estonie</li>
            <li data-value="65" onclick="setinfos('country',65);"> Égypte</li>
            <li data-value="66" onclick="setinfos('country',66);"> Sahara Occidental</li>
            <li data-value="67" onclick="setinfos('country',67);"> Érythrée</li>
            <li data-value="68" onclick="setinfos('country',68);"> Espagne</li>
            <li data-value="69" onclick="setinfos('country',69);"> Éthiopie</li>
            <li data-value="70" onclick="setinfos('country',70);"> Finlande</li>
            <li data-value="71" onclick="setinfos('country',71);"> Fidji</li>
            <li data-value="72" onclick="setinfos('country',72);"> Îles (malvinas) Falkland</li>
            <li data-value="73" onclick="setinfos('country',73);"> Micronésie</li>
            <li data-value="74" onclick="setinfos('country',74);"> Îles Féroé</li>
            <li data-value="75" onclick="setinfos('country',75);"> France</li>
            <li data-value="76" onclick="setinfos('country',76);"> Gabon</li>
            <li data-value="77" onclick="setinfos('country',77);"> Royaume-Uni</li>
            <li data-value="78" onclick="setinfos('country',78);"> Grenade</li>
            <li data-value="79" onclick="setinfos('country',79);"> Géorgie</li>
            <li data-value="80" onclick="setinfos('country',80);"> Guyane Française</li>
            <li data-value="81" onclick="setinfos('country',81);"> Guernsey</li>
            <li data-value="82" onclick="setinfos('country',82);"> Ghana</li>
            <li data-value="83" onclick="setinfos('country',83);"> Gibraltar</li>
            <li data-value="84" onclick="setinfos('country',84);"> Groenland</li>
            <li data-value="85" onclick="setinfos('country',85);"> Gambie</li>
            <li data-value="86" onclick="setinfos('country',86);"> Guinée</li>
            <li data-value="87" onclick="setinfos('country',87);"> Guadeloupe</li>
            <li data-value="88" onclick="setinfos('country',88);"> Guinée Équatoriale</li>
            <li data-value="89" onclick="setinfos('country',89);"> Grèce</li>
            <li data-value="90" onclick="setinfos('country',90);"> Géorgie du Sud et les Îles Sandwich du Sud</li>
            <li data-value="91" onclick="setinfos('country',91);"> Guatemala</li>
            <li data-value="92" onclick="setinfos('country',92);"> Guam</li>
            <li data-value="93" onclick="setinfos('country',93);"> Guinée-Bissau</li>
            <li data-value="94" onclick="setinfos('country',94);"> Guyana</li>
            <li data-value="95" onclick="setinfos('country',95);"> Hong-Kong</li>
            <li data-value="96" onclick="setinfos('country',96);"> Îles Heard et Mcdonald</li>
            <li data-value="97" onclick="setinfos('country',97);"> Honduras</li>
            <li data-value="98" onclick="setinfos('country',98);"> Croatie</li>
            <li data-value="99" onclick="setinfos('country',99);"> Haïti</li>
            <li data-value="100" onclick="setinfos('country',100);"> Hongrie</li>
            <li data-value="101" onclick="setinfos('country',101);"> Indonésie</li>
            <li data-value="102" onclick="setinfos('country',102);"> Irlande</li>
            <li data-value="103" onclick="setinfos('country',103);"> Israël</li>
            <li data-value="104" onclick="setinfos('country',104);"> Île de Man</li>
            <li data-value="105" onclick="setinfos('country',105);"> Inde</li>
            <li data-value="106" onclick="setinfos('country',106);"> Territoire britannique de l'océan Indien</li>
            <li data-value="107" onclick="setinfos('country',107);"> Iraq</li>
            <li data-value="108" onclick="setinfos('country',108);"> Iran</li>
            <li data-value="109" onclick="setinfos('country',109);"> Islande</li>
            <li data-value="110" onclick="setinfos('country',110);"> Italie</li>
            <li data-value="111" onclick="setinfos('country',111);"> Jersey</li>
            <li data-value="112" onclick="setinfos('country',112);"> Jamaïque</li>
            <li data-value="113" onclick="setinfos('country',113);"> Jordanie</li>
            <li data-value="114" onclick="setinfos('country',114);"> Japon</li>
            <li data-value="115" onclick="setinfos('country',115);"> Kenya</li>
            <li data-value="116" onclick="setinfos('country',116);"> Kirghizistan</li>
            <li data-value="117" onclick="setinfos('country',117);"> Cambodge</li>
            <li data-value="118" onclick="setinfos('country',118);"> Kiribati</li>
            <li data-value="119" onclick="setinfos('country',119);"> Comores</li>
            <li data-value="120" onclick="setinfos('country',120);"> Saint-Kitts-et-Nevis</li>
            <li data-value="121" onclick="setinfos('country',121);"> Corée du Nord</li>
            <li data-value="122" onclick="setinfos('country',122);"> Corée du Sud</li>
            <li data-value="123" onclick="setinfos('country',123);"> Kosovo</li>
            <li data-value="124" onclick="setinfos('country',124);"> Koweït</li>
            <li data-value="125" onclick="setinfos('country',125);"> Îles Caïmanes</li>
            <li data-value="126" onclick="setinfos('country',126);"> Kazakhstan</li>
            <li data-value="127" onclick="setinfos('country',127);"> Laos</li>
            <li data-value="128" onclick="setinfos('country',128);"> Liban</li>
            <li data-value="129" onclick="setinfos('country',129);"> Sainte-Lucie</li>
            <li data-value="130" onclick="setinfos('country',130);"> Liechtenstein</li>
            <li data-value="131" onclick="setinfos('country',131);"> Sri Lanka</li>
            <li data-value="132" onclick="setinfos('country',132);"> Libéria</li>
            <li data-value="133" onclick="setinfos('country',133);"> Lesotho</li>
            <li data-value="134" onclick="setinfos('country',134);"> Lituanie</li>
            <li data-value="248" onclick="setinfos('country',248);"> Afrique du Sud</li>
            <li data-value="249" onclick="setinfos('country',249);"> Zambie</li>
            <li data-value="250" onclick="setinfos('country',250);"> Zimbabwe</li>
            <li data-value="251" onclick="setinfos('country',251);"> Serbie-et-Monténégro</li>
            <li data-value="252" onclick="setinfos('country',252);"> Antilles Néerlandaises</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Personally, I would just hide the List Items that do not match what has been entered, simply reducing the number of possible items the user has to select from.

Comment: @Twisty Look the post or the Fiddle ...

Comment: I have been. I see you're binding to onKeyDown. Part of the problem I see is that you don't have a good way to seek the value. For example on Line 23: `$(this).innerText == res`, I would first change that to `$(this).text() == res`, but also now you have to iterate over all the items instead of using a JQuery Selector. You could change the HTML a little: `<li data-value="50" data-label="Costa Rica"  onclick="setinfos('country',50);"> Costa Rica</li>` and then use `$("#custom-select li[data-label^='" + res + "']:first")`

Comment: Meant to use: `$(".customSelect li[data-label^='" + res + "']:first")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so just in case someone is interested in the finality.

This is what it takes :

```
  function search(res){
    var matchedVille = [];
    matchedVille = $('ul>li:not(.not)').filter(function(){
        var regExp = new RegExp ("^ "+res.toLowerCase().sansAccent());
        return this.innerHTML.toLowerCase().sansAccent().match(regExp);
    });
    return $(matchedVille[0]).position().top;
  }
```

Precision : `sansAccent()` Is a function that remove accent.

```
  function scrollToLi(res){
    if(res != 0){
    var offset = toScroll.position().top;
    toScroll.scrollTop(res - offset);
    }
  }
```

And this is how it is call :  `scrollToLi(search(res))` with res a string created by adding key tapped.

And there you have a [working example on jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Baldrani/9u59cm31/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example where the list is filtered https://jsfiddle.net/xu83c23f/1/

```
function filterLiElements(text) {
    $('#customSelect > li').each(function() {
      if ($(this).text().toUpperCase().search(res) > -1) {
        $(this).show();
      } else {
        $(this).hide();
      }
    });
}
```